# Problema na combinação jwplayer + chrome

Tags: javascript, java, html

Olá, estou utilizando o jwplayer em uma aplicação web e estou encontrando um problema com o chrome para executar os comandos da ferramenta. O problema ocorre quando é clicado no "play" pela segunda vez. Quando isso acontece, o componente dá o play e logo em seguida entra em pause, ocasionando o mal funcionamento da ferramenta.

No firefox a ferramenta funciona de acordo com o esperado.

Segue o trecho html

```
<h:form id="panel">
...
<h:form id="veiculacoes">
...
<h:commandLink action="#{veiculacao.colocarPlayTrue}"
    onclick="listenRadio('#{veiculacao.url}', #{veiculacao.tempoRelativo});">
    <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    <f:ajax render=":panel:veiculacoes"></f:ajax>
</h:commandLink>
<h:commandLink action="#{veiculacao.colocarPlayFalse}">
    <i class="fa fa-stop"></i>
    <f:ajax render=":panel:veiculacoes :form-rc"></f:ajax>
</h:commandLink>
...
<div id="myElement"></div>
...
</h:form>
...
</h:form>
```

E o JavaScript

```
function stopjwplayer() {
   jwplayer("myElement").stop();
}
```

```
function listenRadio(url, seekpoint) {
    if (jwplayer("myElement").getState() == "PLAYING"
            || jwplayer("myElement").getState() == "BUFFERING"
            || jwplayer("myElement").getState() == "PAUSED") {
        jwplayer("myElement").remove();
    }
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        'file' : url,
        'height' : 0,
        'width' : '100%',
    });
    jwplayer("myElement").seek((seekpoint - 1) * 60);
    jwplayer().play(true);
    currentUrl = url;
```

`jwplayer().onDisplayClick(function() {
        jwplayer().play(true);
    });
}`

Espero que alguém possa ajudar.

Obrigado